# Python-Sphinx: replace standard front page with custom page

Tags: formatting, latex, python-sphinx

I am happily exploring the capabilities of Sphinx and all looks quite OK so far. What I would do now is to replace the standard latex formatting of the front page with a couple of commands from a custom LaTeX-Documentclass of mine. In code:

```
    [...]
    \begin{document}

    \ifdefined\shorthandoff
      \ifnum\catcode`\=\string=\active\shorthandoff{=}\fi
      \ifnum\catcode`\"=\active\shorthandoff{"}\fi
    \fi

    %%%%%%%% I needed to comment out / suppress these standard commands %%%%
    %\pagestyle{empty}
    %\maketitle
    %\pagestyle{plain}
    %\sphinxtableofcontents
    %\pagestyle{normal}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \phantomsection\label{\detokenize{SoftwareTools/DeviceScanner/indexDeviceScanner::doc}}

    %%%% These custom commands can be injected via .. raw:: latex %%%%
    \renewcommand\documentTitle{Title Text}
    \renewcommand\documentPurpose{Purpose Text}
    \renewcommand\documentOwnerUnit{Text}
    \renewcommand\documentValidFor{Text}
    \renewcommand\documentAuthors{Author}
    \begin{fcdFrontPage}
    \fcdVersionTableRow{###}{Text}{Text}{Text}{Text}
    \end{fcdFrontPage}
```

I already discovered the directive *.. raw:: latex* which I use to inject my custom commands,  this works nicely. But how do I get rid of the standard title page formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question in a dupli-post in tex.stackexchange:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/485505/136433

Comment: The link does not work. It says "This question was removed from TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation".